# Create PowerShell PSObject in C# cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, object

New to C# but experienced in PowerShell. Taking over someone else's code. Writing a compiled PowerShell module, and trying to figure out how to create an object based on returned data. Right now, code returns a string:

```
ServerResponse<UCCSiteModel> requestModel = this.MakeRequest("/site/api/", "site", "GET", this.Credentials, queryString);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

if (requestModel != null && requestModel.Response != null)
{
    builder.AppendLine("SiteID: " + requestModel.Response.SiteID);
    builder.AppendLine("Identity: " + requestModel.Response.SiteName);
    builder.AppendLine("Site Code: " + requestModel.Response.SiteCode);
    builder.AppendLine("Contact Name: " + requestModel.Response.ContactName);
    builder.AppendLine("Contact Number: " + requestModel.Response.ContactNumber);
    builder.AppendLine("Contact Email Address: " + requestModel.Response.ContactEmailAddress);
    builder.AppendLine("Address: " + requestModel.Response.Address);
    builder.AppendLine("City: " + requestModel.Response.City);
    builder.AppendLine("State: " + requestModel.Response.State);
    builder.AppendLine("Post Code: " + requestModel.Response.PostCode);
    builder.AppendLine("Time Zone: " + requestModel.Response.Timezone);
    builder.AppendLine("Longitude: " + requestModel.Response.longitude);
    builder.AppendLine("Latitude: " + requestModel.Response.latitude);                    
    this.WriteResponse(requestModel, builder.ToString());
}
```

How do I create an object from `requestModel.Response` to send back to PowerShell instead of the string? When writing PowerShell, I would normally use `New-Object PsObject`, and then `Add-Member`. Not sure how to do that in C#, or what it's called (so I can search). Anyone?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just return `requestModel` or `requestModel.Response`?

Comment: because that contains a few things like a big blob, that I don't want in the object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can mirror the behavior of `Add-Member` simply by calling `Add()` on the `Members` property of your `PSObject` (I would change the property names to CamelCase for ease of accessibility in PowerShell):

```
if (requestModel != null && requestModel.Response != null)
{
    PSObject responseObject = new PSObject();

    responseObject.Members.Add(new PSNoteProperty("SiteID", requestModel.Response.SiteID));
    responseObject.Members.Add(new PSNoteProperty("Identity", requestModel.Response.SiteName));
    // and so on etc... 
    responseObject.Members.Add(new PSNoteProperty("Latitude", requestModel.Response.latitude));

    this.WriteObject(responseObject);
}
```

Comment: So that gives me the same issue that other methods I've tried to. In the WriteResponse line, responseObject reports "Argument type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' is not assignable to parameter type 'string'

Comment: Sorry, was under the impression that you were inheriting the `Cmdlet` class (in which case you would return the object with `WriteObject()` and not `WriteResponse()`)

Comment: That did the trick. I super appreciate everyone's comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing all the details I can't say this is the best plan, but here is what I would do.  You could define a class and then return it.  So you would create a new class such as below:

```
public class RequestResponse {
    public int SiteID { get; set;}
    public string Identity { get; set; }
    other fields...
}
```

Next, in the code you posted, you would create the object and then fill the properties of the class.

```
var response = new RequestResponse();

if (requestModel != null && requestModel.Response != null)
{
    response.SiteID = requestModel.Response.SiteID;
    response.Identity  = requestModel.Response.Identity ;

    fill in other fields...
    this.WriteResponse(requestModel, response);
}
```

I hope this gets you started in the right direction.

Wade